# Is there an integer $x$ where $(0 \leq x < 19)$ such that $x ≡ 123^{12345} \pmod {19}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm working on a questions which says:

> Is there an integer $x$ where $(0 \leq x < 19)$ such that $x ≡ 123^{12345} \pmod {19}$?

I got an answer of $18$ mod $19$, though I'm not sure whether I'm correct.

Can you help me verify this answer?

Comment: Actually it's $11$.  But, as quid noted, you don't really need that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$123 \equiv 9 \mod 19$, so the answer is the same as $9^{12345} \mod 19$.
Now $19$ is a prime, so Fermat says $a^{18} \equiv 1 \mod 19$ for any $a \not\equiv 0 \mod 19$.  Since $9 = 3^2$, $9^9 \equiv 3^{18} \equiv 1 \mod 19$.
Now $12345 \equiv 6 \mod 9$, so $9^{12345} \equiv 9^6 \mod 19$.  This is small enough to compute directly: $9^6 = 531441 \equiv 11 \mod 19$.

Comment: How come there's 12345 ≡ 6 mod 9 when all these while the it's mod 19? @RobertIsrael

Comment: Since $9^9 \equiv 1 \mod 19$, $9^{9x+y} \equiv 9^y \mod 19$.  So to find $9^{12345} \mod 19$ you want to look at $12345 \mod 9$, not $\mod 19$.

Answer (score 2):

There definitely is such an integer. It is the remainder of the euclidean division of $123^{12345}$ by $19$, which is an integer in the interval you claim.

It is not necassary to determine the value to answer the question you quote.

Comment: Assuming you have to, would the value be 18 mod 19? @quid

Comment: No. It would be 11 as Robert Israel said in a comment. To calculate this you can use the method mentioned in another answer. However if you are supposed to answer the question you quoted it is as said not necessary and in my opinion also not desirable to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Since $(123,19)=1$, by the Fermat's little theorem we have $$123^ {18}\equiv 1\bmod 19$$
can you continue?

Comment: Do I need to write 12345 = 685 x 18 +15 as well? I wrote it down just in case I need to use it later in the calculations @Fermat

Comment: Yes. that's correct.

Comment: $123^{12345}$ ≡ $9^{12345}$ ≡ $(123^{771})^16$ x $9^{15}$ ≡ 1 x $3^9$ mod 19. Is this correct?

Comment: please use **\times** to write multiplication symbol.

Answer (score 1):

${\rm mod}\ 19\!: \overbrace{\color{#c00}{9^{\large 18}}\equiv \color{#c00}1}^{\rm little\ Fermat}\!\!\Rightarrow 123^{\large\overbrace{15+18\rm K}^{\Large 12345}}\equiv 9^{\large\rm 15+18K}\equiv 9^{\large 15}(\color{#c00}{9^{\large 18}})^{\large\rm K}\equiv 9^{\large 15} \color{#c00}1^{\large\rm  K}\equiv 9^{\large 15}\,$

Finally $\,\ 9^{15}\equiv \dfrac{\color{#c00}{9^{18}}}{9^3}\equiv \dfrac{\color{#c00}1}{9^3}\equiv\left(\dfrac{1}9\right)^3\equiv\left(\dfrac{-18}9\right)^3\equiv (-2)^3\equiv -8\equiv 11$ [all mental arithmetic]